# Docrtine 2, Symfony 3.0.4-DEV on user registration, UUID is generated instead of proper annotation

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, symfony

This issue has seriously been driving me crazy for the past day and I have no idea what is causing it.

I am using the latest stable build of Symfony.

I have setup a user registration form that works fine on the actual registration part. However, when persisting to the database, I get a DriverException saying that the entity was unable to be persisted because it's generating a UUID for the table id instead of an auto_increment integer, like I have specified in the entity file for the user.

`An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO users (id, *other columns*) VALUES (?, *other*)' with params ["bdf5cafe-073e-11e6-ac7d-15bb6ded6019", *other values*]:`

If I check the profiler for Symfony it's showing that Doctrine is calling `SELECT UUID()`.

Here is the code excerpt for the Entity ID:

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;
```

I have no idea why this is occurring. I have searched everywhere and not found an answer for it. If anyone has any ideas, I'd really appreciate it.

Thank you.

Comment: what kind of database it is and what is database table DDL ?

Comment: MySQL database. The problem happens on both a local instance and a ClearDB instance. Engine is InnoDB

Comment: what kind of annotations you have at entity class ? also, what kind of driver do you use (is it pdo_mysql) ? also make sure you dont have double declaration of `$id` attribute, or some conflicting constructor or prepersist code ...

Comment: Annotations are `@ORM\Table(name="users")`, 
and `@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")`. Driver is, pdo_mysql, yes.

Comment: what if you try to use @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO") or @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")

Comment: Still a UUID for both. I just checked.

Comment: If @mrok's advice wont work, try to backup your entity files, and try to generate them from database: http://codingtools.net/cheatsheet/symfony-doctrine  (and if that works, backport your changes to generated file)

Comment: Just tried. Rebuilt the entities from the database, didn't work. Replaced the entities, destroyed the database and rebuilt the database, didn't work. This is why it's been so frustrating.

Comment: can you try to replace type="integer" by type="guid" ?